# Vector field in spherical coordinate

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a simple vector field on the surface of a sphere of radius 1

```
\bar{u} = 1/\Sin[\theta] \hat{\theta}
```

for that I have written the following

```
r[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] 
\[CurlyPhi][x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y] 
\[Theta][x_, y_, z_] := ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]] (*Unit vectors*)
 ex[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[\[Theta][x, y, z]] Cos[\[CurlyPhi][x, y]] 
ey[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[\[Theta][x, y, z]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi][x, y]] 
ez[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[\[Theta][x, y, z]] (*Components of the Vector Field*) 
Vx[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sin[\[Theta]]*ex[x, y, z] 
Vy[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sin[\[Theta]]*ey[x, y, z] 
Vz[x_, y_, z_] := -1/Sin[\[Theta]]*ez[x, y, z]
VectorPlot3D[{Vx[x, y, z], Vy[x, y, z], Vz[x, y, z]}, {x, 0.1,0.9}, {y, 0.1, 0.9}, {z, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

but it does not yield anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the `\bar{u} = 1/\Sin[\theta] \hat{\theta}` in Mathematica code and describe its meaning.

Comment: You forget to write the arguments of theta. E.g.:  Vx[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sin[\[Theta]]*ex[x, y, z] should read:  Vx[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sin[\[Theta][x,y,z]]*ex[x, y, z]

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. I am trying to plot a velocity field over a sphere where the velocity vector  is u has magnitude 1/sin \theta and it is in theta direction. I tried your suggestion but the output is still an empty box.

Comment: I am trying to plot a velocity field over a sphere where the velocity vector is u has magnitude 1/sin \theta and it is in theta direction.  \bar{u} = 1/\Sin[\theta] \hat{\theta} is the simple velocity field.

Comment: The error mentionned by Daniel Huber for Vx is also found for Vy and Vz. Fix this and the arrows will appear.

Comment: Hi Jean, of course I did that, there is a singularity in \theta = 0, I am not taking that value neither, nevertheless, it won't work.